# Moq is nullifying my methods

Tags: c#, moq

I have a child class `Form` inheriting `Document`. `Document` has several virtual methods. When I create a new `Mock<Form>`, Moq appears to override the virtual methods in `Document` with blank methods. For example, `Document` defines

```
public virtual bool HasPrivilege(...) { ... }
```

and `Form` calls it like this:

```
HasPrivilege(Reorder, session);
```

However, this call is not happening, no exception is being thrown, and my test is failing. When I try to debug, the breakpoints inside the method aren't hit unless I remove the `virtual` keyword. How can I cause Moq not to nullify these methods?

Comment: That is by design. You will need to show more about what it is you are actually trying to do so that help can be provided.

Comment: You need to include a [MCVE] in your question. That means showing how you set up the mock, how you invoke it etc.

Comment: It is the expected behavior from moq. I think you should read [moq's quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, @litelite for the link to the [quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart). I should be using `Setup(...).CallBase()` for the virtual methods which I do not want overridden.

Comment: And if you want that call-base behavior as a default for all virtual members (even those not explicitly setup), you can use `new Mock<ClassToBeMocked> { CallBase = true, };`.